# Как получить данные из multiple select Angular

Tags: php, angular

Никак не получается забрать данные из  multiple select'a.

Вот формочка

```
           <form action="" class="auth-form" method="POST">


                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <strong>Выберите управления:</strong>
                                        <select id="slim-select" name="select[]" multiple="multiple">
                                        <optgroup label="Выбрать все управления">
                                      <?php  foreach($pageData["listDepartment"] as $key => $value) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php  echo $value["idDepartment"];?>">
                                        <?php  echo $value["idDepartment"]." - ".$value["departmentName"];?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select>

                                    </div>




                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="contractNumber" class="form-label"><b>Номер контракта</b>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="text" id="contractNumber" name="contractNumber"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="Введите номер контракта">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="contractTitle" class="form-label"><b>Предмет контракта</b>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="text" id="contractTitle" name="contractTitle"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="Введите предмет контракта">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="contractDate" class="form-label"><b>Дата заключения
                                                контракта</b>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="date" id="contractDate" name="contractDate"
                                            class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="stage" class="form-label"><b>Периодичность
                                                исполнения</b></label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="stage" name="stage">
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option value="6">6</option>
                                            <option value="7">7</option>
                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                            <option value="9">9</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                            <option value="12">12</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="stage">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <hr>
                                            <h4>Этап 1</h4> <input type="text" name="stageName1" id="stageName1"
                                                value="1" hidden=""><label for="dateBegin1"
                                                class="form-label"><b>Дата начала этапа</b></label><input
                                                type="date" id="dateBegin1" name="dateBegin1" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3"><label for="dateEnd1" class="form-label"><b>Дата
                                                    завершения этапа</b></label><input type="date" id="dateEnd1"
                                                name="dateEnd1" class="form-control"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="block-wrap"></div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Добавить
                                        контракт</button>
```

А вот функция в Angular

```
$scope.addContract = function() {
    

    var stageCount = angular.element("#stage").val();
    var stageArr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i<=stageCount;i++){

        var stageNameInfo = "#stageName"+i;
        var dateBegin1Info = "#dateBegin"+i;
        var dateEndInfo = "#dateEnd"+i;
        $scope.stageName = angular.element(stageNameInfo).val();
        $scope.dateBegin = angular.element(dateBegin1Info).val();
        $scope.dateEnd = angular.element(dateEndInfo).val();


        stageArr.push = ({
            name: $scope.stageName,
            dateBegin: $scope.dateBegin,
            dateEnd: $scope.dateEnd
        }
        )

    }
    $scope.stageArr = stageArr;


 
    $scope.nameDp = angular.element("#nameDp").val();
    $scope.contractNumber = angular.element("#contractNumber").val();
    $scope.contractTitle = angular.element("#contractTitle").val();
    $scope.contractDate = angular.element("#contractDate").val();

    //этап 1
    $scope.stageName1 = angular.element("#stageName1").val();
    $scope.dateBegin1 = angular.element("#dateBegin1").val();
    $scope.dateEnd1 = angular.element("#dateEnd1").val();

            //этап 2
            $scope.stageName2 = angular.element("#stageName2").val();
            $scope.dateBegin2 = angular.element("#dateBegin2").val();
            $scope.dateEnd2 = angular.element("#dateEnd2").val();
             //этап 3
             $scope.stageName3 = angular.element("#stageName3").val();
             $scope.dateBegin3 = angular.element("#dateBegin3").val();
             $scope.dateEnd3 = angular.element("#dateEnd3").val();
                    //этап 4
                    $scope.stageName4 = angular.element("#stageName4").val();
                    $scope.dateBegin4 = angular.element("#dateBegin4").val();
                    $scope.dateEnd4 = angular.element("#dateEnd4").val();
                           //этап 5
             $scope.stageName5 = angular.element("#stageName5").val();
             $scope.dateBegin5 = angular.element("#dateBegin5").val();
             $scope.dateEnd5 = angular.element("#dateEnd5").val();
                    //этап 6
                    $scope.stageName6 = angular.element("#stageName6").val();
                    $scope.dateBegin6  = angular.element("#dateBegin6").val();
                    $scope.dateEnd6 = angular.element("#dateEnd6").val();
                                   //этап 6
                                   $scope.stageName7 = angular.element("#stageName7").val();
                                   $scope.dateBegin7  = angular.element("#dateBegin7").val();
                                   $scope.dateEnd7 = angular.element("#dateEnd7").val();
                                                  //этап 8
                    $scope.stageName8 = angular.element("#stageName8").val();
                    $scope.dateBegin8 = angular.element("#dateBegin8").val();
                    $scope.dateEnd8 = angular.element("#dateEnd8").val();

                                   //этап 9
                                   $scope.stageName9 = angular.element("#stageName9").val();
                                   $scope.dateBegin9  = angular.element("#dateBegin9").val();
                                   $scope.dateEnd9 = angular.element("#dateEnd9").val();

                                                  //этап 10
                    $scope.stageName10 = angular.element("#stageName10").val();
                    $scope.dateBegin10  = angular.element("#dateBegin10").val();
                    $scope.dateEnd10 = angular.element("#dateEnd10").val();

                                   //этап 11
                                   $scope.stageName11 = angular.element("#stageName11").val();
                                   $scope.dateBegin11  = angular.element("#dateBegin11").val();
                                   $scope.dateEnd11 = angular.element("#dateEnd11").val();
    
                                                  //этап 12
                    $scope.stageName12 = angular.element("#stageName12").val();
                    $scope.dateBegin12  = angular.element("#dateBegin12").val();
                    $scope.dateEnd12 = angular.element("#dateEnd12").val();



    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/cabinet/contracts/addContract",
        data: $.param({
            nameDp: $scope.nameDp,
            contractNumber: $scope.contractNumber,
            contractTitle: $scope.contractTitle,
            contractDate: $scope.contractDate,
            stageName1: $scope.stageName1,
            dateBegin1: $scope.dateBegin1,
            dateEnd1: $scope.dateEnd1,
            stageName2: $scope.stageName2,
            dateBegin2: $scope.dateBegin2,
            dateEnd2: $scope.dateEnd2,
            stageName3: $scope.stageName3,
            dateBegin3: $scope.dateBegin3,
            dateEnd3: $scope.dateEnd3,
            stageName4: $scope.stageName4,
            dateBegin4: $scope.dateBegin4,
            dateEnd4: $scope.dateEnd4,
            stageName5: $scope.stageName5,
            dateBegin5: $scope.dateBegin5,
            dateEnd5: $scope.dateEnd5,
            stageName6: $scope.stageName6,
            dateBegin6: $scope.dateBegin6,
            dateEnd6: $scope.dateEnd6,
            stageName7: $scope.stageName7,
            dateBegin7: $scope.dateBegin7,
            dateEnd7: $scope.dateEnd7,
            stageName8: $scope.stageName8,
            dateBegin8: $scope.dateBegin8,
            dateEnd8: $scope.dateEnd8,
            stageName9: $scope.stageName9,
            dateBegin9: $scope.dateBegin9,
            dateEnd9: $scope.dateEnd9,
            stageName10: $scope.stageName10,
            dateBegin10: $scope.dateBegin10,
            dateEnd10: $scope.dateEnd10,
            stageName11: $scope.stageName11,
            dateBegin11: $scope.dateBegin11,
            dateEnd11: $scope.dateEnd11,
            stageName12: $scope.stageName12,
            dateBegin12: $scope.dateBegin12,
            dateEnd12: $scope.dateEnd12
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(result){

       
    })
```

}

*Помогите, пожалуйста, получить данные из

```
 <select id="slim-select" name="select[]" multiple="multiple">*
```

Comment: $scope.departametns= angular.element("#slim-select").val(); 
Это же не так делается.... да?

Comment: Проще всего отправить сериализованную форму методом  `serialize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил к селектору модель.

```
<select id="slim-select" name="select[]" multiple="multiple" ng-model="data.model">
```

В Angular

```
namesDp: $scope.data.model
```